# Is the skew normal distribution log-concave?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, skew-normal-distribution

Is the [skew normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) distribution [log-concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#Log-concave_distributions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this property was proved by Azzalini himself in his paper "A class of distributions which includes the normal ones". You can find it there as **Property D**, which is used to prove strong unimodality of the skew normal density.